# java classes and objects does not have proper output

Tags: java, class, object

I've been working on this for hours just as practice and everything should work perfectly as I've used another class and objects example as a template for this. when I put in the scanner "shirt", "M", and "400", this is what comes up.

```
Shirt
M
400
Shirt isShirt@f6f4d33
```

```
public class Shirt {

    private String shirtColor;
    private String size;
    private int price;

    public Shirt(String shirtColor, String size, int price) {

    }

    public void setColor(String shirtColor) {
        this.shirtColor = shirtColor;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return this.shirtColor;
    }

    public void setSize(String size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public String getSize() {
        return this.size;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return this.price;
    }

}
```

and this is my main that I run the previous class from(my driver)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String shirtColor;
        String size; 
        int price;

        shirtColor = scan.next();
        size = scan.next();
        price = scan.nextInt();

        Shirt shirter = new Shirt(shirtColor, size, price);
        System.out.print("Shirt is" + shirter);

    }
}
```

Comment: Override `toString()` method in your Shirt class

Comment: Your constructor is empty too. You need to add statements like `this.shirtColor = shirtColor`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is printing `Object` class with its `HashCode`. If you are looking to print the value set in `Shirt` Object, override `toString()` method in your `Shirt` Class. Then, in your `main`, just print out `shirter.toString()`.

Change your constructor as shown below:

```
public Shirt(String shirtColor, String size, int price) { 
   this.shirtColor=shirtColor; 
   this.size=size; 
   this.price=price 
}
```

Comment: it just prints out null, null, and 0

Comment: Have you tried after  shirtColor = scan.next();
        size = scan.next();
        price = scan.nextInt();

        Shirt shirter = new Shirt(shirtColor, size, price);
        System.out.print("Shirt is" + shirter.toString()); I believe

Comment: @simonshampoo Because your contructor has an empty body. You are in Java, all is hand job here, buddy :)

Comment: In your constructor public Shirt(String shirtColor, String size, int price) {
this.shirtColor=shirtColor; this.size=size; this.price=price
    }

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement a `toString` method:

```
public class Shirt {

    private String shirtColor;
    private String size;
    private int price;

    ...

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "shirtColor: " + shirtColor + ", size: " + size + ", price: " + price;
    }
}
```

As @SwaritAgarwal notices, you need to implement the constructor so that it sets all the arguments.

Comment: it just prints out, null, null, and 0

Comment: @simonshampoo can you print the arguments? I think the problem lies there, not in the implementation of `toString`

Comment: white, medium, 100

Comment: Are those printed values or that's what you're typing?

Comment: I just noticed, you've implemented the constructor wrong, see @SwaritAgarwal's answer

Comment: I got it! my constructor was empty. thank you very much though!!

Comment: @simonshampoo no problem, if it's helpful, consider upvoting / marking as correct ;>

Answer (score 1):

When you call

```
System.out.print("Shirt is" + shirter);
```

what happens is the following:

1. Java compiler tries to "cast" the object `shirter` to String. I put "cast" in apostrophes as it is not a real type cast, but calling its method `toString()`.
2. The `toString()` method is inherited from the `Object` class (the parent class of all the classes). The default definition is that it returns the name of the class (in your case `Shirt` followed by its internal hash code.
3. If you want to have your object nicely printable (and also nicely displayed in the debugger in your IDE etc.), you should redefine the `toString()` method in your `Shirt` class.